# How do I remove myself from an event I'm hosting on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I made a bachelor party event page for my husband so I could add all guests into one spot, then I'd leave... but I cannot figure out how to leave. I'm hosting on Facebook, I can't "not attend", I can't remove the event page, I have no clue how to switch hosting ownership so I can leave.

Answer (score -1):

Have your husband or his best man start the event and invite you with the ability to add friends. Add who you want then click not attending. I don't think you can leave an event you created yourself. I was searching for an answer to this too and it just clicked for me.